# Lipschitz condition

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the expression
$$
\left|y_1-y_2 + \alpha\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}(y_1-c_i)-\prod_{i=1}^{n}(y_2-c_i) \right] \right|
$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha \in (0,1)$, and $y_1,y_2$ are real variables. I would like to show that the given expression is strictly less than 
$$
L\left|y_1-y_2 \right|
$$
where $L$ is a Lipschitz constant. If anyone out there has some ideas about how to do this, I would love to hear them! Also, if anyone out there thinks that this is impossible, please let me know why.

Comment: Of course this could not be *strictly less* than $L|y_1-y_2|$ when $y_1=y_2$. Absolute value cannot be strictly less than $0$.

Comment: You have been blessed with finding the Lipschitz constant of a smooth (analytic, even!) function (namely that of $y \mapsto y - \alpha \prod_{i = 1}^n (y - c_i) = F(y)$, say). Now compute the derivative of $F$ and find out if its bounded. If it's bounded, then your bound for $L$ is precisely your bound for $F'$ by the Mean Value Theorem. If $F'$ is unbounded, then by MVT there is no finite, global Lipschitz constant (however, if you restrict $y_1, y_2$ to a bounded domain, there is always a Lipschitz constant equal to the supremum of $F'$ over that domain).

Answer (score 2):

This is not Lipschitz when $n\ge 2$. Take $n=2$ and $c_1=c_2=0$: the expression becomes 
$$\left|y_1-y_2 + \alpha(y_1^2-y_2^2)\right|\ge \alpha|y_1^2-y_2^2|-|y_1-y_2|=|y_1-y_2|\Big(\alpha|y_1+y_2|-1\Big)$$
Since $\alpha|y_1+y_2|-1$ can be arbitrarily large, the estimate you seek is impossible.